# Solr Date formatting

Tags: java, json, solr

I have solr dates:

TimeFrame_From:2018-02-28T05:00:02.0Z 
TimeFrame_To: 2018-02-28T06:00:02.0Z

I have written a code using simple date format

```
public void validateParameters(String TimeFrame_From,String TimeFrame_To,String Feed_Type,String ITEM_PROCESSING_STATUS) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    Date  date = sdf.parse(TimeFrame_From);
    Date date2=sdf.parse(TimeFrame_To);

    if ((!TimeFrame_From.equals(sdf.format(date)))||(!TimeFrame_To.equals(sdf.format(date2)))){
        //System.out.println("Time Frame is invalid");
    }
```

When I run this I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-02-27T21:00:01.0Z"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.Error.validateParameters(Error.java:27)
    at com.Error.main(Error.java:60)
```

Also please guide me on how to check for conditions where

TimeFrame_from < TimeFrame_to and TimeFrame_from = TimeFrame_to

Can someone please help me at the earliest am really in need of this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.0Z'"

Comment: No. Am getting this as part of an url and am parsing that date format to this code. So i cant change the format here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

I replaced the above with the below code 
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'0Z'");

This fixed the error.